# columns need to separate based on value and group on them

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Name     Address    City        State    Id        IdType
---------------------------------------------------------
XYZ      123 Rd     New York    NY       123D      Code1
XYZ      123 Rd     New York    NY       56A45     Code2
XYZ      123 Rd     New York    NY       D45256    Code3
XYZ      123 Rd     New York    NY       345TT     Code2
ZZZ      456 St     Richmond    VA       1564      Code2
ABC      879 Rd     Tampa       FL       5687AB    Code1
ABC      879 Rd     Tampa       FL       546YYY    Code3
```

Result:

```
Name    Address    City        State    code1     code2    code2_II    Code3
XYZ     123 Rd     New York    NY       123D      56A45    345TT       D45256
ZZZ     456 St     Richmond    VA                 1564
ABC     879 Rd     Tampa       FL       5687AB                         546YYY
```

Appreciate any help.

[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijEQ.jpg)

Comment: select  Name,Address,City,state,
          max(case when id = 'Code1' then id end) as 'Code1',
       max(case when id = 'Code2' then id end) as 'Code2',
    (Case when max(id)<>min(id) then min(id) end) as 'Code2_II,'
     max(case when id='Code3' then id end ) as 'Code3 
from t1
group by Name,Address,City,state;

--but it is not giving cod2_II value into new column, it is giving same value from code1 or code2.

Comment: To conform the post with [our model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    Address, 
    City, 
    State,
    MAX(CASE WHEN IdType = 'Code1' THEN Id END) AS Code1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN IdType = 'Code2' THEN Id END) AS Code2,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN IdType = 'Code2' THEN Id END) 
            <> MIN(CASE WHEN IdType = 'Code2' THEN Id END)
        THEN MIN(CASE WHEN IdType = 'Code2' THEN Id END) 
    END AS Code2_II,
    MAX(CASE WHEN IdType = 'Code3' THEN Id END) AS Code3
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    City, 
    State
```

The `MIN/MAX` trick on `Code2` allows the query to deal with two different values of `Code2`.